# SignalR Core JS Client not passing Authorisation headrs on "Upgrade " Request

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I Have to implement a push notification service using ASP .Net Core.  as obvious choice is to use SignalR Core.

Our platform setup is using Azure App gateway and it is configured to not allow unauthenticated requests.

We have setup WebSockets communication with SignalR.

Under the hood , SignalR Core follows these steps:

1. POS ../negociate -> OK with hub_token and supported transport
2. GET (sends Upgrade header and WebSockets token)../Hub?id={hub_token} -? fail

when investigating why the step 2 does not upgrade the connection to a WebSocket connection , I have noticed that the GET request is missing Authorization header. Obviously AG block this request and doesn't even get to the API.

I have tried manually to make a "handshake" with postman.
the above steps :

1. OK
2. included Authorization JWT header -> result 101 ,and Fiddler confirm the connection is opened.

I have researched the documentation and found that Authorization headers are not supported.

did anyone tried any workaround ? hen is the next release of the @aspnet/signalr client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the final resolution is: 
that in browsers is a limitation for sending JWT header along with HTTP 101 UPGRADE

Answer (score 0):

Did you specified the `accessTokenFactory`?

```
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("/myhub", {
    accessTokenFactory: () => {
        // Get and return the access token.
        // This function can return a JavaScript Promise if asynchronous
        // logic is required to retrieve the access token.
    }
})
.build();
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=dotnet#configure-bearer-authentication).

Comment: This is exactly the part that does not work.  JWT Token will be sent as Query string not as part of the header. as it should be. Your example does this : ../Hub?id=5u4uNZpKFNpEWyS5ioVhFg&access_token={jwt token} .. While JWT token should be in the Authorization: bearer {jwt token} -

Comment: SignalR works as you said: token in query string. It's your duty to take that from query strings parameters and then validate the token in your authorization stack

Comment: I have stated in the original post that Azure AppGateway blocks the request. As such the request does not reach to the API itself. . so nothing to handle in the "Authorization" middleware